# Quickest way to copy records from one table to another sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlbulkcopy

I have a database table (Employee) with following fields: EmpID, EmpName. I have a second table (EmployeeVersion) with following fields: PKID(auto), EmpID, EmpName, Month, Year.

What would be the quickest way to copy data from Employee table to EmployeeVersion table. The Month, Year would either contain the month and the year when the data was copied or values sent to Stored procedure (@Month, @Year) from c# code. Please provide solution for both scenarios.

As far as I know, I can't used following statement because the number of columns don't match in both tables:

```
Insert Into EmployeeVersion (EmpID, EmpName, Month, Year) select * from Employee
```

Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: Select Specific columns From EMPLOYEE table.

Comment: How would I populate Month & Year in EmployeeVersion table because these two fields do not exist in Employee table?

Comment: Check GORDON's solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify columns in the select statement and escape reserved words used as column names `Month, Year` with `[]`:

```
Insert Into EmployeeVersion (EmpID, EmpName, [Month], [Year])  
select EmpId, EmpName, MONTH(GETDATE(), YEAR(GETDATE()) from Employee
```

And stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CopyEmployee] 
    @Month INT,
    @Year INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    Insert Into EmployeeVersion (EmpID, EmpName, [Month], [Year]) 
    select EmpId, EmpName, @Month AS [Month], @Year AS [Year] from Employee;
END
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

Why are you storing month and year in separate columns?  Why not just put the date in when the data is inserted?

```
Insert Into EmployeeVersion (EmpID, EmpName, Month, Year)
    select EmpID, EmpName, month(getdate()), year(getdate())
    from Employee;
```

Note that you can have a column called `CreatedAt` that is assigned automatically.  You would define it as:

```
create table . . .
    CreatedAt datetime not null default getdate()
```

Then the `insert` would look like:

```
Insert Into EmployeeVersion (EmpID, EmpName)
    select EmpID, EmpName
    from Employee;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, there are two scenarios, in the first scenario I can use the automated date but it may not be current date all the time so how would I implement the scenario 2, where I am transfering the date parameter to the stored procedure. So suppose I transfer '@Month', '@Year' as params to stored procedure, how would I change the Insert statement to accommodate these params instead of month(getdate()), year(getdate()). will it simply becomes: 'Insert Into EmployeeVersion (EmpID, EmpName, Month, Year)
    select EmpID, EmpName, '@month', '@year'
    from Employee'

Comment: sorry I should have mentioned that the comment box was treating '@Month' as user without the quotes so I added quotes. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the columns in the select:

```
Insert into EmployeeVersion SELECT EmpId, EmpName, MONTH(getdate()), YEAR(getdate()) from Employee
```

Regards.